# Better way to test rails counter cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a better / simpler way to test a rails counter cache in RSpec than this:

```
let(:question) { create(:question) }

it "has a counter cache" do
  expect {
    create(:answer, question_id: question.id, user_id: question.user.id)
  }.to change {
    question.reload.answers_count
   }.by(1)
end
```

Also, is it good practice to use `#create` instead of `#build` on the factory here? Since just building it would throw an error (as the required fields of the factory would not get set with build).

Comment: I generally do not believe in testing core rails features, as they have plenty of test cases already built in from the framework as is. It seems you are using `counter_cache` as is... You might even be able to reference the actual test cases for ActiveRecord that pertain to this, and adapt it to your purpose. Sorry I can't contribute otherwise, but perhaps that might help you sleep at night?

Comment: Honestly, I could go either way on this. You are trying to test that it is correctly applied to your model the way you think it is. It's a fine line between that and testing the rails functionality itself.....

Comment: In my company we do things like `it { is_expected.to belong_to(:channel) }`, I don't know if it's a best practice, but it is directly supported by rspec and it breaks if someone is cleaning up a file and accidently drops a line from a model.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has already tested the increment counter. What we should do is to test the `belongs_to :question` association of Answer with the `counter_cache` enabled.

```
RSpec.describe Answer, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:question).counter_cache(true) }
end
```